# How to access data from a "SELECT * FROM" mysql_fetch_array query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got this in my php file

```
$atr_info = "SELECT * from attributes";
$atr_info2 = mysql_query($atr_info) or die ("Couldn't get attributes");
$atr = mysql_fetch_array($atr_info2)or die ("Couldn't make array");

die ($atr['attribute'][n]);
```

The attributes table has 3 columns: id,attribute,tooltip 
and has lots of rows. I want to be able to return the value of the row "n" in column attribute but it doesn't work it returns the first row of the column and the shows the Nth letter in that field, how can I make it work?

Comment: mysql_fetch_array() returns one row at a time from the resultset. To read multiple rows, mysql_fetch_array() is run through a loop. In your example, you have run mysql_fetch_array() only once and so it always returns the first row of the column. Please try and follow the examples from the answers below.

Comment: Great thanx for the explanations I understand where ive gone wrong :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$i = 1;
$rows = array();
$atr_info2 = mysql_query("SELECT * from attributes") or die ("Couldn't get attributes");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($atr_info2)) {
  $rows[$i] = $row;
  $i++;
}
```

Now you cann access the attribute-column in row 45 like that:

```
echo $rows[45]['attribute'];
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you rewrite your query like this

```
$atr_info = 'SELECT * from attributes LIMIT $n, 1'
$atr_info2 = mysql_query($atr_info) or die ("Couldn't get attributes");
```

and then

```
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($atr_info2) or die ("Couldn't make array"))
{
     echo $row['tooltip'];
}
```